# Should I use <page type="list"> or <listpage> in angular2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, components

I'm getting started with angular2 and wanted to create a todo-list web app. The UI should consist of two pages (=components) which get slide in/out via JavaScript.

The first one shows all todos in a vertical list and the other one shows additional details when a todo item from the list is clicked.

I'm now asking myself, what's the right way in angular2 to declare the page components?

Should I build a generic component like this?

```
<page type="list"></page>
<page type="detail"></page>
```

Or should I create a new component for each page?

```
<listpage></listpage>
<detailpage></detailpage>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, without knowing more details, my gut sense would be that the latter would be more appropriate, i.e. create a new component for each page.

You require two fundamentally distinct types of entities:

- a collection and
- a single item from that collection.

The first solution that you propose, i.e. a generic component, would be more suitable to multiple entities that all share some basic underlying structure but differ in some (but not all) details, e.g., two different collection views that both list all items but format those items in two different ways. To force that strategy onto your use case would require your generic `page` component to have no universally shared structure: what template or logic would you share between a todo-list collection and a single todo-item from that collection? Everything would depend on the value of the `type` attribute. Then what meaning would `page` have? Essentially nothing.

Your latter suggestion, i.e. having two distinct components for these two different entities, seems more in the true spirit of how angular components are meant to be used.

I suppose one could argue that a more generic `page` component/view could have some valuable structure that persists for both the `list` view and the `detail` view, e.g. main title, navigation links, user info, etc. However, even if you implemented that, I think you'd want to eventually create separate (more deeply nested?) components for the whole list versus for an individual item, which eventually comes back around to implementing your latter suggestion.

I think a useful model is the example code provided on the official Angular2 web site. I could point to several different examples, but I think the clearest parallel to your situation is in the "Advanced Documentation" section, under the ["Routing & Navigation" heading](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). There they provide code that separates components as follows:

- `hero-list.component`: This would seem to parallel your `listpage`.
- `hero-detail.component`: This would seem to parallel your `detailpage`.

Clearly they've separated out these two parts of the app into distinct components.

This sort of strategy decision may also depend on the size/complexity of your "entities". If your "list" and "detail" views were both extremely simple, I suppose you could distinguish between them within a single component (e.g. `page`), just using an attribute (e.g. `type`). However, in a todo app, I can't imagine either a list view or a detail view being extremely simple. Thus trying to squash both into a single `page` component would make the component too complex.